# c# typemock taking mocked result of last case

Tags: c#, typemock

I am trying to mock using a method call using typeMock. I have mocked method in different cases but every time I am getting the same result. Following is code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class HomeControllerSpec
{
    User _fakeUser;
    ProfileSettingsBL _profileSettingBL = null;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        // Inital setup
    }


    [TestCase]
    public void DisconnectOutlookCalendarForUserRegisterWithEmail()
    {
        _fakeUser = new User();
        _fakeUser.LoginType = 4; // This is be different in each case

        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => _profileSettingBL.RetrieveUserProfile()).WillReturn(_fakeUser);

        HomeController ctrl = new HomeController();
        var result = ctrl.Disconnect();

        Assert.IsTrue(result.Content);
    }



    [TestCase]
    public void DisconnectOutlookCalendarForUserRegisterWithName()
    {

        _fakeUser = new User();
        _fakeUser.LoginType = 5; // This is be different in each case

        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => _profileSettingBL.RetrieveUserProfile()).WillReturn(_fakeUser);

        HomeController ctrl = new HomeController();
        var result = ctrl.Disconnect();

        Assert.IsTrue(result.Content);
    }

}
```

When different test case calling `Disconnect` method of HomeController I am getting `_fakeUser.LoginType == 4` always. But when I am removing one of test case both cases running perfectly.

Any Idea?

Comment: You are using a shared variable between the tests. make `_fakeUser` local to the test and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using the `[Isolated]` attribute? 
It instructs Typemock Isolator to clean up the result of the test after the test is completed.